# Recover disk space after aborted Ubuntu USB boot

Tags: macos, ubuntu, boot, usb

I created a bootable USB stick with Ubuntu 12.04 on it using [these](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) instructions.
Then I tried booting my MacBook Pro with the USB by holding <kbd>alt</kbd> during start-up.
I chose the option `Try Ubuntu` in the list that appeared.

I got a black screen for about 5 minutes, so I decided to abort the boot by holding the power button for a while. The laptop turned off, and after turning on and booting into OSX all was fine.
However, I think I am missing some hard drive space after this failed USB boot. How can I check if I am actually missing drivespace and how can I restore this (remove the residual files left by the USB boot)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible, that you have less space because of this live-cd.

When you "try" ubuntu, no data will be saved on your harddisk. All the distros mount a `temp-harddisk` in form of a `RAM-disk`. So no data will be written on your harddisk.

Answer (score 1):

The boot process *shouldn't* write anything to your disk, the point of trying Linux is so that you don't go through the effort of installing anything.  It shouldn't be persistent, and in the case of Ubuntu to my knowledge the only thing it may do is automount any drives it detects but it won't write anything to them as the OS is stored on the USB device and if it writes anything at all(doubtful) it would write it to the USB drive.